# Function FTPhost not defined when called from FTPtool module

Tags: python, module

Having error when using FTPtool module for Python

```
class FTPHost(object):
"""Represent a connection to a remote host.

A remote host has a working directory, and an ftplib object connected.
"""

def __init__(self, ftp_obj):
    """Initialize with a ftplib.FTP instance (or an instance of a
    subclass). Use the classmethod connect to create an actual ftplib
    connection and get an FTPHost instance.
    """
    self.ftp_obj = ftp_obj

def __repr__(self):
    return "%s(%r)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.ftp_obj)

def __str__(self):
    return "<%s at %s:%d (%s)>" % (self.__class__.__name__,
        self.ftp_obj.host, self.ftp_obj.port, self.ftp_obj)

@classmethod
def connect(cls, host, port=21, user=None, password=None, account=None,
            ftp_client=ftplib.FTP, debuglevel=0, timeout=None):
    """Connect to host, using port. If user is given, login with given
    user, password and account. The two latter can be None, in which case
    ftplib will set the password to 'anonymous@'. You can choose which
    class to instance by means of ftp_client.
    """
    ftp_obj = ftp_client()
    ftp_obj.set_debuglevel(debuglevel)
    if timeout is not None:
        old_timeout = socket.getdefaulttimeout()
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(float(timeout))
        ftp_obj.connect(host, port)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(old_timeout)
    else:
        ftp_obj.connect(host, port)

    # And log in.
    if user:
        ftp_obj.login(user, password, account)
    return cls(ftp_obj)
```

When calling FTPhost.connect(server, name, pass) i get the error FTPhost not defined. New to Python and have tried looking all around the code but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fresh to ftptool as well, and I met the same problem.
Here's my way.

from ftptool import FTPHost